# NSString placeholder for class name

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, nsstring

How do you use a placeholder for the name of a class?  I have methods that based on incoming parameters reference other classes by name.  In the crude example below I need to be able to load one of three ViewControllers based on the name alone (not an array of ViewControllers as this is just one example).

```
-(void)loadViewController:(int)vcNumberToLoad
{
    NSString *vcOne = @"firstViewControllerName";
    NSString *vcTwo = @"secondViewControllerName";
    NSString *vcThree = @"thirdViewControllerName";

    NSArray *vcArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:vcOne, vcTwo, vcThree, nil];

    NSString *nameOfVCToLoad = [vcArray objectAtIndex:vcNumberToLoad];

    UIViewController |VALUE OF nameOfVCToLoad| = [[UIViewController alloc] init]; // What is the code to get the value of nameOfVCToLoad to be used as the instance name of the UIVC class
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:|VALUE OF nameOfVCToLoad| animated:NO];

}
```

For example, if the method was run with a parameter of '1'

```
NSString *nameOfVCToLoad = [vcArray objectAtIndex:vcNumberToLoad]; //this would = secondViewControllerName

UIViewController secondViewControllerName = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewControllerName animated:NO];
```

Other questions seem to intimate that [NSClassFromString:nameOfVCToLoad] could be along the lines of what I need, if so how?

Comment: Why do you care about **local** variable name?

Comment: This was purely an example to try and illustrate my main point of wanting to know how to use NSString as a placeholder for the actual name of a class.

Comment: the variable names are for making the code readable during development session. in _runtime_ no var's name will be used by the processor, it works _addresses_ only. so, what you are asking about defining a variable name dynamically during _runtime_, makes not too much sense in practice.

Comment: In my example, there could be 100 dynamically created buttons all using the same selector method.  This method can only really take the button tag, this tag could then be used to load a relevant ViewController.  My thought would be the tag could correspond to the index of any array, the item at the index would be an item name.  This item name could be used for multiple things, one of which being the name of the corresponding ViewController to load.  It was my thought that a placeholder could be used in this instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing yourselves about object. You are looking for this one

NSClassFromString(vcOne) will help you to do the dynamic class selection

isKindOfClass will help you to identify that whether that class is the given class

```
-(void)loadViewController:(int)vcNumberToLoad
{
    NSString *vcOne = @"firstViewControllerName";
    NSString *vcTwo = @"secondViewControllerName";
    NSString *vcThree = @"thirdViewControllerName";


    firstViewControllerName *fvc = nil;
    secondViewControllerName *svc = nil;
    thirdViewControllerName *tvc = nil;


    NSArray *vcArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:vcOne, vcTwo, vcThree, nil];

    NSString *nameOfVCToLoad = [vcArray objectAtIndex:vcNumberToLoad];


    UIViewController *aLoadedViewController = [[NSClassFromString(nameOfVCToLoad) alloc] init];

    if ([aLoadedViewController isKindOfClass:[NSClassFromString(vcOne)]]) {

        fvc = aLoadedViewController;

    }
    else if ([aLoadedViewController isKindOfClass:[NSClassFromString(vcTwo)]]) {

        svc = aLoadedViewController;

    }
    else if ([aLoadedViewController isKindOfClass:[NSClassFromString(vcThree)]]) {

        tvc = aLoadedViewController;

    }

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:aLoadedViewController animated:NO];

}
```

Comment: Somewhat over complicated way of doing it... +1 anyway.

Comment: what if there were many viewControllers?  You would need to write a very long and not very dynamic set of if statements?

Comment: if you want to find out and give some extra data on that particular view controller, then you must do it. other wise no need of it.

Comment: like fvc.someproperty = somevalues; then you need the if loop to differentiate it. otherwise just use the aLoadedViewController. Every your own view controller is a UIViewcontroller by inheritance . so navigation controller expects a viewcontroller.thats it.

Comment: This is perhaps the closest to what I'm looking for here.  I will post a more specific question to my actual problem to see if I need to rethink my approach.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Objective-c has `Class` type, that exists as part of the `NSObject`.

More accurately will be:

```
-(void)loadViewController:(int)vcNumberToLoad {
     Class vcOne = [FirstViewControllerName class];
     Class vcTwo = [SecondViewControllerName class];
     Class vcThree = [ThirdViewControllerName class];

     Class viewControllerClass;
     // switch between classes

     UIViewController *viewControllerToPush = [[viewControllerClass alloc] init];
     // push UIViewController
}
```

**Benefit** from doing like this is in the **type checking** at compile time.